# Use PostgreSQL database in SQL script

Tags: postgresql

I'm creating 3 databases from a single file:

```
CREATE DATABASE "products"
  WITH
  OWNER = postgres
  ENCODING = "UTF8"
  CONNECTION LIMIT = -1
  IS_TEMPLATE = False;

CREATE DATABASE "accounts"
  WITH
  OWNER = postgres
  ENCODING = "UTF8"
  CONNECTION LIMIT = -1
  IS_TEMPLATE = False;

CREATE TYPE role as ENUM ('employee', 'admin', 'customer');
```

Now I would like the type role to be created in the accounts database. The current script just creates the role in the 'default' postgres DB. I am used to MySQL syntax where I could use the 'use ' command. Any idea how I can use a similar command for a PostgreSQL script?

For additional context: this SQL file is executed in a PostgreSQL docker container upon initialisation.

I tried the following:

- use the 'use' command. -> not recognised.
- use the 'select' command. -> invalid.

Comment: In `psql` you use `\connect` to switch to a different database. What MySQL calls a database is in reality a schema. So if you want to mimic MySQL's behaviour, just create two _schemas_ in Postgres, not two databases.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thank you for your suggestion! at the moment I have multiple microservices connecting to the same database server (but every service has their own database). I would prefer to keep it like that. I suppose I could give every service their own database server though..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PostgreSQL you have to specify the database when you open a connection to the server. You can not switch to a different database using SQL.

From the [documentation of the low-level API for opening connections](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/libpq-connect.html):

> An application program can have several backend connections open at one time. **(One reason to do that is to access more than one database.)**

But as @a_horse_with_no_name already pointed out if you are using [`psql`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) you can use the command `\connect` to open a new connection to a different database.

Comment: Thanks! I am aware of the \c functionality in psql. I (initially) wanted to do it in a SQL file, but since this is not possible I guess I have to use a .sh script when the container is initialised.